# How to grep a section of a file in bash shell

Tags: linux, grep

How can I "grep" the lines between an occurrence of some string1 and the (Nth) occurrence of some string2.

e.g.

if the file has line:

A
**B

C

D

E**
F
G
**B

C

E**
Q

I want to get the lines in bold (those that begin with a B and end with an E).

Can this be done using grep? or some other Unix command line tool?

Comment: This sounds as a tast for sed.  However my sed-fu is not as good as Nicole's so I am just pointing at an close match.  http://superuser.com/questions/513393/converting-strings-in-input-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grep` is not well suited for this task, you need to go one tool "up":

```
sed -n '/^B/,/^E/p' infile
```

Output:

```
B
C
D
E
B
C
E
```

With regards to the Nth requirement, I think its easiest if you again advance one tool "up", namely awk:

```
awk '/^B/ { f = 1; n++ } f && n == wanted; /^E/ { f = 0 }' wanted=2 infile
```

Output:

```
B
C
E
```

The flag `f` will be set when `/^B/` is encountered and unset when `/^E/` occurs, much in the same way the sed notation works. `n` keeps a tally of how many blocks have passed and when `f == 1 && n == wanted` is true, the default block will be executed (`{ print $0 }`).

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly does it do?
I understand that send goes over an input stream, I am guessing the syntax here means something like (don't print)[-n] but print [p] everything from a regexp /^B/ to [,] regexp /^E/ ?

Comment: Is there a way to inject some separator between those two found blocks?

Comment: @epeleg: the sed example works as you assume, all command following the range are executed whilst the input is in that range. Its a bit complicated to insert separators with sed, I would rather use awk instead, see the latest edit.

Comment: You can add a separator with `sed` like this: `/^B/,/^E/ { /^E/G; p; }`

Answer (score 3):

@Thor's `sed` command cannot be beaten, but with the following `perl` script I try to address the part of your question in parenthesis: "... the (Nth) occurrence ...".

Usage:

```
./script <start-regex> <end-regex> [N]
```

Examples with the file in your question:

```
$ ./script "B" "E" < examplefile
B
C
D
E
B
C
E

$ ./script "B" "E" 2 < examplefile
B
C
D
E
F
G
B
C
E
```

There is no error checking or whatsoever and the script is non-greedy, i.e. from `A B C D E E F` only `B C D E` will be grep'ed with N=1.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($ARGV[2] != "") { $n = $ARGV[2] } else { $n = 1 }
$begin_str = $ARGV[0];
$end_str = $ARGV[1];

while(<STDIN>) {
  if($_ =~ $begin_str) { $flag=1 }             # beginning of match, set flag    
  if($_ =~ $end_str && $flag eq 1) { $i++ }    # i-th occurence of end string

  if($i eq $n) {                               # end of match after n occurences of end string
    $flag=2;
    $i=0; 
  }

  if ($flag ge 1) {                            # append currrent line to matching part
    $out.=$_;
  }

  if($flag eq 2) {                             # after detection of end of match, print complete match
    print $out;
    # print "---\n";                           # separator after a match
    $out="";
    $flag=0;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I might use this as well in the future, but for now I believe the sed solution is my way to go.

Comment: looking at this code again, I really like it because I can modify it to suit my exact needs. (like maybe appending the iteration number at the beginning of each line for example).

Comment: can you explain why you are concatenating to $out instead of just printing line by line?

Comment: @epeleg: You can't print line-by-line (I had that at first, too), because then the sequence `A B D` will result in `B D`, although there is no "end terminator" `E`. Apart from that, this gives you an easy way to put in a "separator between those two found blocks" (I included that as a comment in the script now).

Comment: Thinking about it again, even though you are absolutely right about what you said, for my needs its ok and even desired to get the `B D` in your sample. so I will go with direct printing (saves all the string concatenation).